# How to map two strings using java

Tags: javascript

I have two strings 
Listing1(one in html format)

```
<ul>
    <li id="1"></li>
    <li id="2"></li>
    <li id="3"></li>
    <li id="4"></li>
    <li id="5"></li>
    <li id="6"></li>
</ul>
```

Listing2(one in json format)

```
{1:"r1",4:"r2"}
```

I need to fill the html string with the json data provided in listing 2 based on json key and id in html.
Can any one help me to solve this issue.

Thanks
Jineesh

Comment: check your question again - can't read.

Comment: can you show the HTML format please?

Comment: I kow a javascript implementation. But you will get an ajax call. I'm not sure if that is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS/JQuery part pseudocode

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     //iterate over the json data; pick up the id and value.
     for(key in jsonData)
     {
        $('#key').val(jsonData[key]);
     }
});
```

Using JQuery is not necessary though.

That's the easier way to solve your problem. Why you need to handle this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

use regular expressions to get the name/values from the JSON String and put them in the HTML.
You can use the split() and replaceAll() methods of the String class to do this.